# How do I send all information in /var/adm/message file to a remote system?

Tags: solaris, syslog

I'm trying to figure out how to send all information that is normally identified in the `/var/adm/message` file on a Solaris system to a remote system.

Comment: What do you mean by _send_ exactly? You could just email the file as an attachment but I guess that's not what you're asking. Please [edit] your question and give some more context and what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do something custom? Just use [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog), that's what it's there for.

Comment: @Grey Hewgill
what would i edit in the syslog config in order to make this all work ?

i understand the basic of syslog but not 100 percent sure how to make /var/adm/message to a remote system

Answer (score 5):

You can simply edit the `/etc/syslog.conf` file and, wherever `/var/adm/messages` appears, duplicate the line and replace `/var/adm/messages` by `@remoteSystem` with `remoteSystem` being the IP address or hostname of the remote server where to send the logs.

eg:

before:

```
...
*.err;kern.debug;daemon.notice;mail.crit    /var/adm/messages
...
```

after:

```
...
*.err;kern.debug;daemon.notice;mail.crit    /var/adm/messages
*.err;kern.debug;daemon.notice;mail.crit    @jaylogserver
...
```

Restart syslogd for the change to be taken into account:

```
# svcadm restart system-log
```

Note that the remote server must be configured to accept remote messages. If on Solaris too, that would be done with this command:

```
# svccfg -s system-log setprop config/log_from_remote = true
# svcadm restart system-log
```

Comment: In docs, multiple actions (right side) are supposed to work.  I could not get it working properly when combined with remote logging, so this multiple line method worked best.  Also note there should be tabs, not spaces, between the selector section and the action.