# Unix solaris syslog conf

Tags: solaris, remote, syslog

How do I transfer the solaris syslogs to another windows server. Please share the source and destination configuration steps in detail.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97988/how-do-i-send-all-information-in-var-adm-message-file-to-a-remote-system  Pretty much an exact duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the `/etc/hosts` file and add the desired windows host with the `loghost` alias to have syslog messages transferred to it.

Another method is to configure the desired destination in the `/etc/syslog.conf` file appropriate to your needs.

See also `man syslog.conf` for more details.